# ¿Por qué Hernán en lugar de Hernando?

Tags: sinónimos

Según mi entender Hernán, Hernando y Fernando son el mismo nombre. Puede que me equivoque, pero da igual. El conquistador Hernán Cortés siempre firmó sus cartas a la rey de España como Hernando. ¿Por qué hoy día se le refiere a él como Hernán y no Hernando? Me parece curioso, ya que éste era evidentemente su preferencia personal.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because even though it is a very interesting question, it is not in the scope of this site: it does not depend on the language but on the person who has using it and probably has some biographical reasons. Instead, it could be asked in History Stack Exchange.

Comment: This is way far from learning Spanish.

Comment: @Ustanak it's not about *learning* Spanish, but it is about the Spanish language. If someone asked why *fer* is a verb in Salamanca and not *hacer*, the answer would be basically the same because similar principles are at work.

Answer (score 4):

The original name is *Frithunanths* or *Ferdinanths* and is a Northern European name.

En español, se habría iniciado la hispanización con algo como *Ferdinand*. Como no concordaba con las normas fonológicas del castellano, adoptose a ellas. La primera manera de hacerlo es simplificar el grupo consonante *-nd* en *-n*. La segunda es añadir una vocal epentética *-o* que rompe el grupo en dos sílabas. Ambas evidentemente perdieron la *-i-* y redujeron el grupo *-rnd-* en *-rn*.

Hay que tener en cuenta que también en el castellano, a diferencia de las demás lenguas románicas ibéricas, la *f* inicial iba perdiéndose, siendo solo consonante aspirante (como la *j* que predomina en la América hispanohablante), que al final se escribía con *h* — de ahí, como toda *h* perdiose su sonido completamente excepto en algunas regiones pequeñas.

Por alguna razón u otra, se ha conservado no solo ambas adaptaciones, sino también la versión con la *f-* y la que carece de ella, por lo que hay cuatro variantes hoy en día.

El porqué de llamar a alguna figura histórica uno u otro es una pregunta que se tendría que dirigir a cada autor sobre sus preferencias personales.

Comment: "The original name is Frithunanths" I choose to consider this proof that the Spaniards descended from the Welsh.